Get count of all child nodes in a tree
What I want is to count all children recursively for each parent.

I have 2 pages:  children.php and function.php.
In my children.php page I have a table of all parents in the db.
in my children.php page I pass each parent to a function to get all
the children recursively, however the function only return 0.

In children.php I have the following:
$r=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `id`,`parent_id` FROM locations WHERE parent_id = '0'");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) 
{
    $data[] = $row;
    $child_id = $row['id'];
    $d = buildtree($data, $child_id);
}
echo count($d);

in function.php I have this code:
function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id, $tree = array())
{
    foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
    {
        if($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id)
        {
            foreach($row as $k => $v)
                $tree[$row['sys_id']][$k] = $v;
            unset($src_arr[$idx]);
            $tree[$row['sys_id']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['sys_id']);
        }
    }
    ksort($tree);
    return $tree;
}

So, what I am looking after is to return an array of all children recursively of each parent and echo the count of this array.

Calling buildtree inside the while loop like that, makes little sense to begin with - you are adding a new record to $data each time, so on the first loop iteration you would call buildtree for the first record, on the second you would call it for the first two records, etc.

In your loop you're overwriting $d on every iteration, so echo count($d); after the loop will output the last $d count

You have tagged your question with PHP & MySQL; which of these two are you implementing the solution in? I recommend you remove one of the tabs and be explicit in your question. Also, add the expected output you want after the counting is complete.

The way you are storing the tree is confusing and difficult to manage.
It's much easier if you use a class to represent a "node" in the tree. Each node has a list of children which make traversing the tree with a recursive function much easier to understand.
If we define a Node class as:
class Node
{
  public function __construct(
    public string $name,
    public array $children = []
  ) { }
}

Each node has a name to display and an array of zero or more child nodes.
Given a simple tree of six nodes:
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \   \ 
 D   E   F

We'll store this using an array to simulate rows in a database table:
$treeData = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 0],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'B', 'parent_id' => 1],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'C', 'parent_id' => 1],
  ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'D', 'parent_id' => 2],
  ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'E', 'parent_id' => 2],
  ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'F', 'parent_id' => 3],
];

The function to build the tree steps through each "row" creating a new Node object. If the node has a parent (parent_id greater than zero) the node is added to the parent's list of children:
function buildtree(array $treeList)
{
    // Keep track of each node's identifier while building the tree
    $nodeList = [];

    foreach($treeList as $treeItem)
    {
      // Create a new node for this tree item
      $node = new Node(
        $treeItem['name']
      );
      
      // Store the new node keyed by id
      $nodeList[$treeItem['id']] = $node;
      
      if ($treeItem['parent_id'] > 0) {
        // Add the node to the parent's list of children
        $parent = $nodeList[$treeItem['parent_id']];
        $parent->children[] = $node; 
      }
    }
    
    // Finally return the root node
    return $nodeList[1];
}

After building the tree you have nodes containing their children, and the children containing their children:
Node {
    +name: "A",
    +children: [
      Node {
        +name: "B",
        +children: [
          Node {
            +name: "D",
            +children: [],
          },
          Node {
            +name: "E",
            +children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      Node {
        +name: "C",
        +children: [
          Node {
            +name: "F",
            +children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }

Because we have a nested structure it's easy to write a recursive function to get the number of nodes at each level:
function countNodes(Node $node)
{
  $count = 0;

  // Count the number of nodes under each child of this node
  foreach ($node->children as $child) {
    $count += countNodes($child);
  }
  
  // The total for the node passed in to the function is
  // the number of children plus one for "this" node
  $count += 1;
  print("Node $node->name total is $count".PHP_EOL);

  return $count;
}

So calling our two functions
$root = buildtree($treeData);
countNodes($root);

We get the output:
Node D total is 1
Node E total is 1
Node B total is 3
Node F total is 1
Node C total is 2
Node A total is 6

